# How to read out specific values from an OWL Ontology using Java

Tags: java, ontology, owl

I've got an OWL Ontology:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1272923485.owl#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xml:base="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1272923485.owl">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about=""/>
  <owl:Class rdf:ID="studypath">
    <owl:disjointWith>
      <owl:Class rdf:ID="module"/>
    </owl:disjointWith>
    <owl:disjointWith>
      <owl:Class rdf:ID="docent"/>
    </owl:disjointWith>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="#docent">
    <owl:disjointWith>
      <owl:Class rdf:about="#module"/>
    </owl:disjointWith>
    <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="#studypath"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:minCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int"
                            >1</owl:minCardinality>
        <owl:valuesFrom>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="#module"/>
        </owl:valuesFrom>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="responsiblefor"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="#module">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="predecessor_module"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#module"/>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#module"/>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="folgemodule"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:minCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int"
                            >1</owl:minCardinality>
        <owl:onProperty>
          <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="offeredfor"/>
        </owl:onProperty>
        <owl:valuesFrom rdf:resource="#studypath"/>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
    <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="#docent"/>
    <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="#studypath"/>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#predecessor_module">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#module"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#module"/>
    <owl:inverseOf>
      <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#folgemodule"/>
    </owl:inverseOf>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#folgemodule">
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="#predecessor_module"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#module"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#module"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#offeredfor">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#studypath"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#module"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#responsiblefor">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#docent"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#module"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <module rdf:ID="Datenbanken">
    <offeredfor>
      <studypath rdf:ID="WIN"/>
    </offeredfor>
  </module>
  <docent rdf:ID="John_Smith">
    <responsiblefor rdf:resource="#Datenbanken"/>
  </docent>
  <module rdf:ID="Softwaretechnik"/>
  <docent rdf:ID="Wayne_Smith">
    <responsiblefor rdf:resource="#Softwaretechnik"/>
  </docent>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Now I am using Java API for querying the ontology. If I have `Wayne_Smith`, for example, how can I query for the module he is responsible for?

Answer (score 1):

Wayne, precisely which api are you using? If it is the Manchester owl api, you'll find some code examples in their documentation [here](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/documentation.html), which should help you to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly and the Java API you're referring to is the [OWL API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/), this should do the trick:

```
/*Load your ontology from a local file and do the initialisations*/
File inputfile = new File("ontologyPath");
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(); ;
OWLDataFactory dataFactory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
OWLOntology yourOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(inputfile);
IRI ontologyIRI = yourOntology.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI();  

/*Get the object property and the individual you're interested in*/  
OWLObjectProperty o_p_responsible_for = dataFactory.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#"+"Responsiblefor"));
OWLIndividual ind_Wayne = dataFactory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#"+"Wayne_Smith"));
/*return the value*/
Set<OWLIndividual> responsibilities_of_Wayne= ind_Wayne.getObjectPropertyValues(o_p_responsible_for, yourOntology);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way: a SPARQL query can used to query the ontology to get the module for which Wayne_Smith is responsible. And there are Java SPARQL libraries (eg: Apache Jena ARQ). Hope this helps.